# Fatal error: Uncaught exception in Zend ServiceManager

Tags: php, zend-framework, servicemanager

I'm having this error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Professor/Controller/WebinarController' in /uov-videos/www/david/plataovirtual/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 526
```

This happens when I'm trying to use:

```
   $app = Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php');
    $application = $app->getMvcEvent()->getApplication();
    $sm = $application->getServiceManager();
    $webinar_controller = $sm->get('Professor/Controller/WebinarController');
```

In a routine outside the original project.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a composer update and/or composer install ;)

Comment: The original project witch has the Controller is already up to date. The problem is how to access an action from a server routine in another project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, configure your PHP version is compatible

Comment: The php versions are the same across de projects.